# Nginx location configuration (subfolders)

Tags: php, http, nginx, server, slim

lets say I've a path like:

```
/var/www/myside/
```

that path contains two folders... let's say
`/static` and `/manage`

I'd like to configure nginx to have an access to:

`/static` folder on `/` (eg. http://example.org/)
this folder has some .html files.

`/manage` folder on `/manage` (eg. http://example.org/manage) in this case this folder contains Slim's PHP framework code - that means the index.php file is in `public` subfolder (eg. /var/www/mysite/manage/public/index.php)

I've tried a lot of combinations such as

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.org;
  error_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/mysite/error.log;
  access_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/mysite/access.log;
  root /var/www/mysite;

  location /manage {
    root $uri/manage/public;

    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location / {
    root $uri/static/;

    index index.html;
  }

  location ~ \.php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

The `/` works correctly anyway `manage` doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? Does anybody know what should I change?

Matthew.

Comment: I don't think `root $uri/(directory);` will work, will it? Surely that would come out to some odd, like `root /manage/manage/public`, not what you want. Or am I misinterpreting what `$uri` does?

Comment: @Bytewave well yea, you're absolutely right it won't work. That's one of milion combinations that I've already tried :) Let's assume that there isn't $uri but `/var/www/mysite/manage/public` and `/var/www/mysite/static` - anyways it doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To access a path like `/var/www/mysite/manage/public` with a URI like `/manage`, you will need to use `alias` rather than `root`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

I am assuming that you need to run PHP from both roots, in which case you will need two `location ~ \.php` blocks, see example below. If you have no PHP within `/var/www/mysite/static`, you can delete the unused `location` block.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.org;
    error_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/mysite/error.log;
    access_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/mysite/access.log;

    root /var/www/mysite/static;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ^~ /manage {
        alias /var/www/mysite/manage/public;
        index index.php;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /manage/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

The `^~` modifier causes the prefix location to take precedence over regular expression locations at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `alias` and `try_files` directives are not together due to [this long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Be aware of [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) in the use of the `if` directive.

Comment: You have multiple [Common mistakes and Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) in your example

Comment: @vladkras such as?