# Drupal Multi-Site setup with sub-directory in NIGNX

Tags: php, nginx, drupal-8, multisite

I'm using Drupal 8, with multi-site setup, located at "/var/www/html/drupal" directory and I'm using NGINX as web-server.

I've following domain names :

1. qa.example.com
2. qa.example.com/v1
3. qa.example.com/v2

Where "qa.example.com" is main domain serving static file (index.html with some info in it). And v1 and v2 are dynamic sites created using Drupal 8 Multi-site.

Since qa.example.com has only 1 static file, I've placed it in Drupal Core directory and pointed virtual host to "/var/www/html/drupal" directory.
As per documentation available in examples.sites.php, I've added sites entry in sites.php as below:

```
<?php
  $sites['qa.example.com.v1'] = 'v1.example.com';
  $sites['qa.example.com.v2'] = 'v2.example.com';
```

When accessing "qa.example.com" it works fine as it has only single index.html file, but when accessing "qa.example.com/v1", I'm being redirected to "qa.example.com/core/install.php" or receiving "404 Not Found" nginx page. I'm not understanding what I'm missing.

Following is NGINX config I'm using :

```
server {
  server_name qa.example.com;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html/drupal;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /v1 {
    root /var/www/html/drupal;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/html/drupal/index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
  location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
  }
  location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
  }
  location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
  }
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
  }
  location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }
  location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
  }
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Following is the directory structure I've:

```
// main directory
/var/www/html/drupal

// my static file for landing domain name
/var/www/html/drupal/index.html

// drupal core files
/var/www/html/drupal/core
// drupal's index.php file
/var/www/html/drupal/index.php
// contrib and custom modules
/var/www/html/drupal/modules

// Site v1 directory as per Drupal's multi-site directory structure.
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/v1
// Site v2 directory as per Drupal's multi-site directory structure.
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/v2
```

I've looked into many references online, but nothing is working.

NOTE : **v1** and **v2** are not actual directory "/var/www/html/drupal".

Following are links which I've referred :

1. [nginx projects in subfolders](https://serverfault.com/a/218837)
2. [Nginx location configuration (subfolders)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467562)
3. [Multi-site with two sites sharing the same domain?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/182603/678)
4. [PHP Apps in a Subdirectory in Nginx](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory)

Comment: Can you tell the folder structure inside your sites folder?

Comment: I've updated question with directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working on multisite setup so i will suggest you,  create directory with domain name in sites directory and make entry to sites.php like below.

```
$sites[directoy name] = 'domain name';
```

For each site you need to make entry in sites.php.
Each domain should have settings.php.

Comment: I've already created directory for each site and added entry in sites.php file.