# Nginx: How to redirect each subfolder to their respective 'public' subfolder'

Tags: regex, laravel, nginx, routes, vhosts

I wanted to see how I can have a domain where I host my PHP projects without having to be creating a vhost for each one.

I mean:

```
https://example.com/projectA -> /usr/share/nginx/html/projects/projectA/public
https://example.com/projectB -> /usr/share/nginx/html/projects/projectB/public
https://example.com/projectC -> /usr/share/nginx/html/projects/projectC/public
```

I guess I should use regular expressions in the 'location' line but I have not succeeded, I get 404 error.

How could I do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this question tagged `.htaccess` and `php`?

Comment: You're right!!, my bad. Sorry.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).