# Rundeck with other site on nginx, other site is php

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, rundeck

I'm hosting up rundeck, along with another site which happens to be php, in nginx on RHEL 7.5.  I've got rundeck working, but can't get the other site working.  I can get it TO the other site, but can't get php to work.  I've followed the instructions at:

[NGINX-multiSite](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

I'm sure it has something to do with my location blocks but can't quite get the hang of adding php support on a non / site.  Anyone have a clue?  Here's my nginx rundeck.conf file (working for nginx, 502 bad gateway error on other site) :

```
server {
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;
server_name myServer.myDomain;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/myLogFile.access.log;

location /wiki {
  alias /var/www/wiki/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4440;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

}

And all I'm doing on the other site (wiki) is throwing out a php version info file.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Tried moving over to port 9000, changing the rundeck.conf for my location block for php from 8080 as well as the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file to point to 9000 (php-frm port).  This helped a little bit.  I now can open an html file at:

http://myServer.myDomain:8080/wiki/index.html

but not a php file there.  It tells me "No input file specified."

Comment: You need to use a nested location for your PHP block so that it inherits the correct `alias`. See the `manage` block in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562)

Comment: Still getting "No input file specified".  Changed the block to:

    location ^~ /wiki {
      alias /var/www/wiki/html;
      index index.php;

      if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /wiki/index.php last; }

      location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }

Comment: Boom!  Had to add the root level php location block as well as the multi-level block, that link was the ticket, thanks Richard!