# NGINX location giving 404 error, even though the directory exists

Tags: nginx

I have my NGINX configuration file set up as so

```
root /var/www/html/tests_manager/webroot;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name qa.kloc.co.uk; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            rewrite ^/uploads/(.*) /uploads/uploadsController.php last;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /support {
        root /var/www/html/support-manager/webroot; #I have checked, this directory exists.
    }

    location = /notifications {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location = /supportSocket {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
```

I want the `/support` location to redirect to a different root, so that when the user tries to access `qa.kloc.co.uk/support` they see the site in the directory `/var/www/html/support-manager/webroot`

My issue is that whenever I try to browse to this URL, I just receive a 404 error. I checked the access logs and they were not helpful. I just see

```
GET /support/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

there is nothing in the error log.

I tried using a rewrite (like with /uploads/) but I don't think I can escape the root directory. I also tried to use `location = /support` and `location ^~ /support` but these had no effect.

I have also tried changing owner of the `/var/www/html/support-manager/webroot/` directory to `www-data` but this did not make a difference.

Please help me with the correct way to write /support location

Comment: The php files are not handled by the locations in your question. Is there another location block (e.g. `location ~ \.php$`)?

Comment: @RichardSmith there is a PHP location block, I missed it from the selection, have added it to my question now. thanks

Comment: You need to use an `alias` and you need to use a nested location for the PHP bits. See the `/manage` block in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).

Comment: great stuff - thanks this is working now @RichardSmith