# Nginx alias/root issue

Tags: php, nginx

Nginx newbie here.

I control the domain `eample.com` and the goal is to have three distinct resources available at the following URLs:

- `example.com` - static landing page
- `example.com/siteA` - PHP application A
- `example.com/siteB` - PHP application B

I have roughly the following file structure on disk:

```
/var/www
├── html
│   └── index.html
├── siteA
│   └── index.php
└── siteB
    └── public
        └── index.php
```

I have the following (simplified) Nginx configuration

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name example.com;

        # Site A
        location /siteA {
                #root /var/www/siteA;
                alias /var/www/siteA/;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }

        # Site B
        location /siteB/ {
                #root /var/www/siteB/public;
                alias /var/www/siteB/public/;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }
}
```

The included file `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` contains the following:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
```

The static landing page at `example.com` works, but attempting to access `example.com/siteA` results in a `Primary script unknown` error.

The `PHP-FPM` pool access log contains lines like this:

`- -  12/Nov/2019:15:57:03 +0200 "GET /siteA/index.php" 404`

I believe that the actual file path that PHP-FPM is trying to open is `/var/www/html/siteA/index.php`, which is obviously wrong.

I'm pretty sure I'm messing up something related with the `root` and/or `alias` directives, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

How can I fix my configuration, without altering the disk file structure?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: The naive way would be to set the real common `root /var/www;` and adjust it everywhere else.

Comment: Keep in mind that `root` appends the location while `alias` drops the location.

Comment: SiteA could use `root` instead of `alias`. SiteB needs to use `alias` unless you internally rewrite the URIs to include `public`. But your snippets file is designed to only work with root.

Comment: @Richard: It is not mandatory to have a unified snippets file.

Comment: Where you must use an `alias`, take a look at the `/manage` block in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).

Comment: I'll try that for `siteB`, but I still don't understand why `siteA` fails to work with the `alias` directive. It works with `root /var/www/` instead of `alias /var/www/siteA/`.