# nginx custom root for certain addresses

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have installed nginx to my VPN. And I'm a very beginner with that so it might be a stupid mistake but I was unable to figure our or google it.

What I'm trying to do and keep failing in it is set the root folder for certain addresses. For example:
mydomain.com/websiteone/ will have root folder in /var/www/websiteone/public/ and 
mydomain.com/websitetwo/ in /var/www/websitetwo/public/

Im using Laravel that why I need to do that.

Here is the confing and what I was attempting in different variations.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    location /websiteone/ {
        root /var/www/websiteone/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ 404;
    }

    location /websitetwo/ {
        root /var/www/websitetwo/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be try `location ^~ /websiteone`. Also, what exactly is not working? Did you restart/reload nginx after the config changes? What do the `/var/log/nginx/access.log` & `/var/log/nginx/error.log` show?

Comment: `root` directive works by concatenating its value with the URI, so the URI `/websiteone/foo` will be located at `/var/www/websiteone/public/websiteone/foo`. You probably need to use `alias` instead.

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani yes I did restart nginx. And error log is empty. Its giving me 404

Comment: @RichardSmith can you please point me to direction how it would look like. I'm beginner here

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562

Answer (score 1):

No need for `alias` or anything fancy *as long as* URL dir path matches to actual directory names of your two Laravel instances (see below).

Also, Laravel has a typical "front controller" URL pattern, which means URLs that do not exist should be bootstrapped through its `index.php`. So:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    location /websiteone/ {
        root /var/www/websiteone/;
        try_files /public$uri /public$uri/ /public/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /websitetwo/ {
        root /var/www/websitetwo/;
        try_files /public$uri /public$uri/ /public/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I made it work for index.html however it doesnt work for php. If its get to index.php it attemps to download something

Comment: Well, you obviously need a`location ~ \.php$ { ...` specifying how you proxy requests to PHP-FPM. That would be different if you're using UNIX sockets vs TCP for it. The answer cannot accommodate complete NGINX config :)

Comment: I added the 
` location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
`

But no difference what so ever

Comment: Could you please give me an example how it should look like I'm clueless here