# Nginx and php-fpm does not properly works with nested locations

Tags: php, linux, nginx, web

I`m trying to set up postfixadmin nginx config file with nested locations and stuck with problem of passing correct **SCRIPT_FILENAME** to php-fpm backend.

Urls that should be passed as postfixadmin scripts starts with /postfixadmin URL.
Part of my config file that serve /postfixadmin files look like this

```
location ~ ^\/postfixadmin.*(\.php|\.css|\.png|\.gif) {

            location ~ (.*\.php)$ {

                    alias /var/www/postfixadmin/public/;

                    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
                    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
                    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
                    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;

                    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                    proxy_read_timeout 500;
            }
       }
```

And problem in this location

```
location ~ (.*\.php)$ {
```

What i want to do is to serve all usrl related to /postfixadmin and with extension ".php" as php scripts and catch up script name as $1 variable. But in fact when I`m trying to access URL /postfixadmin/index.php I get the following header

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Sun, 19 Jan 2020 10:56:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.1
```

So as you can see nginx properly choose location

```
location ~ ^\/postfixadmin.*(\.php|\.css|\.png|\.gif) {
```

And then nginx sees .php in the end of URL and trying to send this to php-fpm backend. But php-fpm answers with 404 status code. And this happens because of empty **SCRIPT_FILENAME**.

Maybe I`m wrong but I think that problem in this location

```
location ~ (.*\.php)$ {
```

Because when I make it looks like this, all works fine and I can pass $1 variable (as name of script) to php-fpm backend.

```
location ~ .*\/(.*\.php)$ {
```

But specify .*/ before location make no sense (because I want to specify just extension with script name) and I`m just try to understand how to do this right.

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured out cause of problem.
Problem was in my dummy regex.

**So i fixed this**

```
location ~ (.*\.php)$ {
```

**To this**

```
location ~ ([^\/]*\.php)$ {
```

So I just exclude "/" symbol from pattern.

The old type of regex include everything before **.php** plus whole URL.

The new one include everything after last "/"

Thats it!