# nginx serve index file from subfolders

Tags: http, nginx, webserver, http-status-code-301, httpserver

I would like to serve an index file from a root folder and one from a subfolder from root.

My nginx server conf looks as follows:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /data/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.txt;

    location / {
    }

    location /a {
        alias   /data/a/;
    }

}
```

and my directory structure looks as follows:

```
/data/:
a  index.txt

/data/a:
index.txt
```

If I then do `curl localhost`, I get the contents of the file `/data/index.txt`.
But `curl /localhost/a` gives me a `301`. 
`curl localhost/a/index.txt` works.

Why can't I access my index.txt with `curl /localhost/a` ?

I tried using a `root` instead of `alias` in the `location /a` block and also tried to specify the `index.txt` for location `/a`, but no success.

I see similar posts, e.g.
[Nginx location configuration (subfolders)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders)
but couldn't yet find the answer.

Comment: I see that when I first call  `curl localhost/a/index.txt`  and then right afterwards call `curl localhost/a`, it works, but then nginx seems to forget this again and I get a 301.

Comment: I am not sure if i got you right but why are you trying to create an alias to the same uri ex: if you brows `/a` it will automatically brows `a` subfolder and serve index.txt no need for an alias in this case !

Answer (score 0):

The `index` directive works with URIs that end with a `/`:

So the URI `/` gives you the contents of `/index.txt` and `/a/` gives you the contents of `/a/index.txt.

If you provide Nginx with a URI of a directory (but without a trailing `/`), the default behaviour is to redirect to the same URI, but with a trailing `/`.

This is just how the `index` directive works. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

---

If you want something other than default behaviour you will have to do it manually using `try_files`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example, to return the contents of an `index.txt` file by providing the URI of the directory without a trailing `/`, use:

```
root /data;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.txt =404;
}
```

Note that the `location /a { ... }` block is **not necessary** in either this example, or the example in your question.