# Serve PHP App from Particular URI Using Nginx + php-fpm: "Primary script unknown" Error

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, fpm

I'm attempting to configure Nginx to serve both a Django application and a Laravel application. I have the Django application working correctly, so now I'd like get the Laravel application served from /snipe-it.

The main part of the nginx config that I'm struggling with is here:

```
    location /snipe-it/ {
        alias /var/www/html/public/;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~* \.php(/|$) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
```

The actual file location of the `index.php` file is `/var/www/html/public/index.php`.

When attempting to reach the Laravel app at `http://127.0.0.1/snipe-it/index.php`, I get "File not found." The log output looks like this:

```
nginx_1        | - -  24/Jun/2020:17:37:40 +0000 "GET /snipe-it/index.php" 404
nginx_1        | 2020/06/24 17:37:40 [error] 17#17: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.30.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /snipe-it/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"
nginx_1        | 172.30.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2020:17:37:40 +0000] "GET /snipe-it/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0" "-"
```

Everything is in a docker container that derives from the official nginx image which uses Debian buster. I believe that first line from the logs is from the php-fpm7.3 process since I set `access.log` to `/proc/self/fd/2` in my `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file. I also set `catch_workers_output` to `yes` hoping that it might provide more insight into where the application is looking for the `index.php` file but it doesn't seem to.

If it's helpful, the permissions of `index.php` looks like this:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 docker www-data  1887 Jun 23 21:13 index.php`

I'm currently running nginx as the www-data user and php-fpm as the docker user in the www-data group. It seems like the "Primary script unknown" error can be caused by a number of issues so any tips on how I can drill down deeper to find any more clues as to where the problem is would be helpful.

FYI, here's my full nginx conf file:

```
upstream intranet {
    server web:8000;
}

upstream prometheus {
    server prometheus:9090;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /static {
        alias /home/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /home/media;
    }

    # Prometheus settings
    location /prometheus/ {
        proxy_pass http://prometheus;
    }

    location /snipe-it/ {
        alias /var/www/html/public/;

        location ~* \.php(/|$) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://intranet;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` with `alias`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to nginx ngx_http_fastcgi_module [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#variables), `$fastcgi_script_name` internal variable contains request URI or, if a URI ends with a slash, request URI with an index file name configured by the `fastcgi_index` directive appended to it. When you using

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

and got a `/snipe-it/script.php` incoming request, an `$uri` internal variable is equal to  `/snipe-it/script.php`, `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` internal variable is equal to `/var/www/html/public/`, and concantenated `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` string becomes `/var/www/html/public//snipe-it/script.php`, which is obviously leads to an absent file. What you can do is

```
    location ~ ^/snipe-it/(?<subpath>.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/html/public/;
        location ~* \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$subpath;
        }
    }
```

Note that this problem does not occur when you use a `root` directive instead of `alias`. However, it is not possible unless you rename `/var/www/html/public` directory to `/var/www/html/snipe-it` (than you can use `root /var/www/html;` instead of `alias /var/www/html/public/;`).