# NGINX giving error 404 even though i set the right directory in location directive block

Tags: reactjs, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

This is my nginx configuration :-

```
server {
      listen 80 ;
      listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite-error.log;    


  #  server_name server_domain_or_IP;
  server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com ;

   location / {
        root /home/mywebsite/frontend;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

  location /services/ {
      root /home/mywebsite/backend/public;
      try_files $uri $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }  

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

- The directory /home/mywebsite/frontend contain a [Reactjs build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build) index.html.
  [image]
- The /home/mywebsite/backend/public contain a laravel framework files.
  [image]

when i access my website using the URL (mywebsite.com/) the reactjs get loaded very will without any issue, but when i use the URL (mywebsite.com/services/) nginx return error 404.

The error got in /var/log/nginx/mywebsite-error.log :-

> [error] 30346#30346: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/services" failed
> (2: No such file or directory)

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Not sure that if `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` is correct. What is inside the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;`. Did you try to config nginx with laravel itself to test.

Comment: @Ted yes when i set the root directory for the virtual server directly to larvavel folder, it worked without any issue

Comment: Seem like problems come from the way you setting `root`. Try to put the root of laravel out of you location tag and keep root of frontend inside the location tag. Reference: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: Is it a problem for you to rename the `/home/mywebsite/backend/public` folder to `/home/mywebsite/backend/services`? Than the solution would be much more simple. Is there only backend that uses PHP, frontend doesn't use it?

Comment: I don't see `index.php` in any of your directories. Also, you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).