# nginx 404 Not Found for php files

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to setup PHP on Nginx. My Nginx is already configured for a Django website. The subdirectory `/wiki` will run php powered software.

```
server {
    server_name = my_domain_name.com;

    # django stuff here

    location/wiki {
        alias /var/www/mediawiki;
        try_files $uri =404;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # i have verified that this does exist on my system
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # more django and certbot stuff
```

With this configuration, `my_domain_name.com/wiki/index.html` can be accessed, but `my_domain_name.com/wiki/info.php` yields a 404 Not Found nginx page. Yet, they both reside in `/var/www/mediawiki`. What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: It has been edited

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)'s [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562), I figured out that I needed to include a nested location php tag:

```
location/wiki {
    alias /var/www/mediawiki;
    try_files $uri =404;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

and php files are served now.