# Wordpress accessible from / and Symfony from /my-other-site/

Tags: wordpress, symfony, nginx, vhosts

I have a huge difficulty to achieve what I want to do on Nginx.

For a client, I have a blog using WordPress and a marketplace using Symfony 5.4. PHP version is 7.4 FPM.

The blog is under folder /var/www/blog/ with user and group www-data:www-data and should be accessible from https://my-domain.com

The marketplace is under folder /var/www/marketplace/ with user and group www-data:www-data and should be accessible from https://my-domain.com/marketplace/

I try a tone of different configurations found on the internet or using ChatGPT (just in case) without success.

Each time I've got a blog working or not and the marketplace is not found or I've got the error "file not found".

Could someone help me to have a basic idea of how to implement it?
The basic configuration will be enough.

I will really appreciate your help :)

EDIT:

Here is my last try. Wordpress is working but when I try to access to https://my-website/symfony/ I've got a 404 not found of Wordpress.

```
client_max_body_size 0;

# DDoS Mitigation
##Limit the number of connections per IP
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=engine_con:10m;
limit_conn_status 429;

##Limit the number of requests per session
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=engine_req:10m rate=50r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=static_req:10m rate=100r/s;
limit_req_status 429;
# End DDoS Mitigation

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-website.fr www.my-website.fr;
    #add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload';
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "0";
    #add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade;
    add_header Referrer-Policy origin-when-cross-origin;
    add_header Feature-Policy "midi 'none';";
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'self' blob: data: https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com;";
    #return 301 https://www.my-website.fr$request_uri;
    return 301 https://my-website.fr$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.fr/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name www.my-website.fr;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload';
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "0";
    #add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade;
    add_header Referrer-Policy origin-when-cross-origin;
    add_header Feature-Policy "midi 'none';";
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'self' blob: data: https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com;";
    #return 301 https://www.my-website.fr$request_uri;
    return 301 https://my-website.fr$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.fr/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name my-website.fr;

    root /var/www/wordpress;

    index index.php;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload';
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "0";
    #add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade;
    add_header Referrer-Policy origin-when-cross-origin;
    add_header Feature-Policy "midi 'none';";
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'self' blob: data: https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com;";
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types application/font-woff application/javascript application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-otf application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype font/otf font/ttf image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/javascript text/plain text/xml;

    auth_basic "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

    # DDoS Mitigation
    limit_conn engine_con 100;
    # End DDoS

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    
    location = (/|/symfony) {
        return 301 https://my-website.fr/symfony/fr/;
    }

    location ~ ^/symfony/ {
        root /var/www/symfony/current/public;
        index index.php;

        # DDoS Mitigation
        limit_conn engine_con 100;

        location ^/symfony/api/ {
            limit_req zone=engine_req burst=5 nodelay;

            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/symfony/(assets|bundles|images|json)/ {
            limit_req zone=static_req burst=10 nodelay;
        }

        location ~ ^/symfony/media/cache/(?!resolve)/ {
            limit_req zone=static_req burst=10 nodelay;
        }
        # End DDoS Mitigation

        location ~ ^/symfony/ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
            # SecRulesEnabled;
            # LearningMode;
            # CheckRule "$SQL >= 8" BLOCK;
            # CheckRule "$RFI >= 8" BLOCK;
            # CheckRule "$TRAVERSAL >= 4" BLOCK;
            # CheckRule "$EVADE >= 4" BLOCK;
            # CheckRule "$XSS >= 8" BLOCK;
            # DeniedUrl "/403.html";
        }

        location ~ ^/symfony/403.html {
            return 403;
        }

        location ~ elfinder\.main\.js$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/symfony/media/cache/resolve/ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        #location ~* \.(ico|css|js|woff|ttf|png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg)$ {
        #    expires 1m;
        #}

        location ~ ^/symfony/index.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
            internal;
        }

        location ~  ^/symfony/uploads {
            if ($request_filename !~* .(gif|jpe?g|jpe|jfif|gif|png|ico|tiff?|pdf|xml|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?|csv)$) {
                return 404;
            }
        }

        location ~ ^/symfony/admin {
            auth_basic "Restricted Area";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd-exports;
            autoindex on;
        }

        location ~ ^/symfony/server/log/(.*)$ {
            add_header Content-Type text/html;
            auth_basic "Restricted Area";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd-tools;
            alias /var/www/symfony/shared/var/log/$1;
            autoindex on;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            return 404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
    }

    location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #The following parameter can be also included in fastcgi_params file
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders

Comment: I test it but got Too many redirection error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using this server configuration below:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name my-website.com;
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php app.php index.html;

    location /symfony {
        root $symfonyRoot;
        rewrite ^/symfony/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @symfonyFront;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/assets/(.*)$ /symfony/assets/$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    set $symfonyRoot /var/www/symfony/public;
    set $symfonyScript index.php;

    # This is for the Symfony application
    location @symfonyFront {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $symfonyRoot/$symfonyScript;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /symfony/$symfonyScript;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /symfony$uri?$args;
    }

    # This is for the wordpress app
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
        # include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```