# Nginx configuration for website in subfolder

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, nginx

I have 2 website build with laravel and codeigniter 4 in the same server with nginx, I want the website1 (laravel) pointing to example.com (/ root of domain) and website 2 (codeigniter) live in example.com/website2 (/website2)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www;

        location /website2 {
           try_files $uri /website2/public/index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location / {
           root /var/www/website1/public;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
}
```

the problem is in website2 the static files is not found, it should located in `/var/www/website2/public/assets/image.jpg`, but it's pointing to `/var/www/website2/assets/image.jpg` (missing /public/).
I try to change the configuration with

```
location /website2 {
    root /var/www/website2/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

but it redirected to the root, another configuration with alias and some combination to remove $uri, but no luck. I try follow [Nginx location configuration (subfolders)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders) (using alias and some if script) it only success on example.com/website2, but when access example.com/website2/page it's not found, it accessible if the url example.com/website2/index.php/page